# Android SQLite Update Query - What Am I Missing

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
package lab.ex1;





import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import lab.ex1.HospitalDatabase.Patient;

public class DisplayPatient extends HospitalActivity {


    @Override


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display);
        displayData();




    }




    private void displayData()
    {

         final List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         final Intent me = new Intent(DisplayPatient.this,UpdatePatient.class);
         final Bundle b = new Bundle();


        //Build new Patient
        PatientData build = new PatientData();

        final TableLayout viewData = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tblDisplay);

        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        queryBuilder.setTables(Patient.patientTableName);


        SQLiteDatabase db = mDatabase.getReadableDatabase();

        String asColumnsToReturn[] = {Patient.patientTableName + "." + Patient.ID, 
                                      Patient.patientTableName + "." + Patient.firstName, 
                                      Patient.patientTableName + "." + Patient.lastName,
                                      Patient.patientTableName + "." + Patient.room,
                                      Patient.patientTableName + "." + Patient.department}; 




        Cursor c = queryBuilder.query(db,asColumnsToReturn,null,null,null,null,Patient.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);



        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            for (int i=0; i< c.getCount(); i++)
            {
                final TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
                Button update = new Button(this);
                TextView display = new TextView(this);


                display.setTextSize(15);

                    update.setX(15);
                    update.setY(10);
                    update.setTextSize(10);


                Button deleteButton = new Button(this);

                deleteButton.setX(100);
                deleteButton.setY(100);
                deleteButton.setTextSize(10);

                deleteButton.setText("Delete");
                update.setText("Update");
                deleteButton.setTag(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Patient.ID)));

                update.setTag(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Patient.ID)));
                newRow.setTag(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Patient.ID)));      // set the tag field on the TableRow view so we know which row to delete

                myList.add(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Patient.ID)));


                build.setID(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex((Patient.ID)))));
                build.setFirstName((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Patient.firstName))));
                build.setLastName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Patient.lastName)));
                build.setDepartment(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Patient.department)));
                build.setRoom(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Patient.room))));





                deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Integer id = (Integer) v.getTag();
                        deletePatient(id);
                        final TableLayout patientTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tblDisplay);

                        View viewToDelete = patientTable.findViewWithTag(id);
                        viewData.removeView(viewToDelete);

                    }
                });

                update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Integer id = (Integer)v.getTag();
                        final TableLayout patientRmv = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tblDisplay);


                        for (Integer delete : myList )
                        {
                            View viewToDelete = patientRmv.findViewWithTag(delete);
                            viewData.removeView(viewToDelete);
                        }

                        b.putString("key", Integer.toString(id));
                        me.putExtras(b);
                        startActivity(me);

                    }
                });


                display.setText(build.toString());
                newRow.addView(display);
                newRow.addView(update);
                //newRow.addView(deleteButton);

                viewData.addView(newRow);
                c.moveToNext();


            }

        }

        else
        {
            TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
            TextView noResults = new TextView(this);
            noResults.setText("No results to show.");
            newRow.addView(noResults);
            viewData.addView(newRow);
        }
        c.close();
        db.close();



    }

    public void deletePatient(Integer id)
    {

            SQLiteDatabase db = mDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
            String astrArgs[] = { id.toString() };
            db.delete(Patient.patientTableName, Patient.ID+ "=?",astrArgs );  
            db.close();
    }



}



package lab.ex1;


import lab.ex1.HospitalDatabase.Patient;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class UpdatePatient extends HospitalActivity {







     Spinner spinner;
     TextView update;
     String up;
     Button check;

     EditText entry;
     String setPosition;
     TextView updateID;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.updatepatient);

        check = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);

        entry = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editUpdate);
        updateID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtIDUpdate);




         Bundle accept = getIntent().getExtras();

         up = accept.getString("key","0");

         updateID.setText(null);
         updateID.setText("ID: "  + up);


        update = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtUpdateMessage);
        update.setText(null);
       // update.setText(up);
         spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnChoice);
         ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this, R.array.arrFields, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

          spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());



          check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    updateDB(entry.getText().toString(),setPosition,up);

                }
            });




    }








    public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
            View view, int pos, long id) {

            update.setText(null);
            update.setText("I will update On " + adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
            setPosition = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();


        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
          // Do nothing.
        }


    }




    public void updateDB(String valuesToUpdate, String field,String ID)
    {




        SQLiteDatabase db = mDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        try
        {
            ContentValues updatePatient = new ContentValues();

            if (field == "First Name")
            {
                updatePatient.put(Patient.firstName, valuesToUpdate);
                String astrArgs[] = { up.toString() };
                db.update(Patient.patientTableName,updatePatient, Patient.ID+"=?", astrArgs);
                //
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            }

        }


        finally
        {
            db.endTransaction();
        }


        db.close();


        Intent me = new Intent(UpdatePatient.this,DisplayPatient.class);
        startActivity(me);

    }
}
```

I am using Android SQLite Database. In my display class, it reads all the entries from the database and displays them along with an update button next to each entry. That entries update button's tag has entries Patient.ID. When the user clicks update, they are taken to the update class where they can select what they want to update, First Name, Last Name, Apartment, Room. Afterward they click update, to which they are taken back to the Display class and they should see there changes. However, when they are taken back, the previous value is still there, the changes do not show up, what am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "taken back"?...Do you mean pressing the back button?

Comment: Yes. When the user presses update on the UpdatePatient form.

Comment: Use startActivityForResults to start the activity. Read the results into onCreate and then assign the values to your views

Comment: Do you have maybe an example or documentation I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Move your displaydata() call from onCreate to onResume.

Comment: Let me test and i'll post back. 5 mins

Comment: The Previous value is still there :(

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it. For some reason the if statements weren't checking out properly